# Battery powered camera and transmitter for outdoor use

Tags: wireless, video, camera, ip-camera

I wish to set up a camera 500 meters from my house to send a live stream of a river over the internet. The camera and transmitter will have to be battery or solar powered and be able to transmit the video signal to my house where I have an internet connection.

Any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: Ubiquiti  (ubnt.com) makes outdoor networking products you’ll likely find useful.  I couldn’t find the link to the external antennae products from my phone (that website is easier to use on a computer than phone).  But you’ll want long range beam antenna.  If there is cellular service in the area it maybe be most economical to get the Netgear LTE modem (LB1121) that powers a camera via POE and power that with a solar cell.  I have this setup, I pay $20/month for a laptop plan SIM card with unlimited (22gb throttle), the camera averages 12gb month.

Comment: Also I’m not sure why the downvote here, it’s a valid on topic question that has answers, it’s not wish-ware.

Comment: Long range WiFi and other wireless transmission requirements can vary by country.  I’m guessing you’re outside the US since you specified meters.  You should edit in your country for the best answers.